# Update fetched rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I have a stored procedure which looks like this:

```
alter procedure newProcedure
    @take int,
    @skip int
as
begin
    set nocount on

    declare @countRowNumbers int;
    set @countRowNumbers = (select count(*) from TableA)

    select * 
    from tableA a
    order by a.ID
        offset ISNULL(@skip,0) rows
        fetch next ISNULL(@take, @countRowNumbers) rows only

    --update only fetched rows (first 100, or second 100)
    -- update TableA set Status = 2
end
```

I have column status which is representing if the row is under processing or not, so when I grab those 100 documents I need to update that Status status to 2.

How can I do that?

Comment: What are `@take` and `@skip`? They have no data type.

Comment: Is there really a need to do paging on the update? Doing so create race conditions.

Comment: `delcare @countRowNumbers int;` is also not valid, and you're missing an `END`.

Comment: sorry guys, I was typing from another remote machine..Please see my updated question. Also any suggestion on how to do a pagging wihout using fetch is most welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining the other answers, using an updatable CTE to carry out the `update` first, then using the [`output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause to capture the ID's updated and then `select` them to return.

```
declare @SelectedId table (id int);

with toupdate as (
      select * 
      from tableA a
      order by a.ID
      offset isnull(@skip,0) rows
      fetch next isnull(@take, @countRowNumbers) rows only
)
update toupdate
    set [status] = 2
output Inserted.id into @SelectedId;

select *
from tableA
where ID in (select id from @SelectedId)
order by ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alter procedure newProcedure
    @take int,
    @skip int
as
begin
    set nocount on

    declare @countRowNumbers int;
    set @countRowNumbers = (select count(*) from TableA)
    
    update tableA set status = 2 where ID in (
    select a.ID
    from tableA a
    order by a.ID
        offset ISNULL(@skip,0) rows
        fetch next ISNULL(@take, @countRowNumbers) rows only )

    --update only fetched rows (first 100, or second 100)
    -- update TableA set Status = 2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use an updatable CTE for this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select * 
      from tableA a
      order by a.ID
      offset ISNULL(@skip,0) rows
      fetch next ISNULL(@take, @countRowNumbers) rows only
     )
update toupdate
    set status = 2;
```

Comment: does not work it says `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure newProcedure, Line 14 [Btach Start Line 12] Invalid column name 'status'`

Comment: @Stefan0309 . . . The column name and table name comes from your question.  The CTE is selecting all the columns.

Comment: yes, but it simply doesnt work..updateing column is not detected outside this select statement.

Comment: ok, I get it, I need to select in in the select clause, in order I can update it :)

Comment: @Stefan0309 . . . Here is a db<>fiddle illustrating the idea:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b02909dd7edeb4f48d9cb4982e64ccb9.

Comment: it works, but the stored procedure doesnt return select query.

Comment: @Stefan0309 . . . Your question --as clearly as I can interpret it -- is "I need to update that Status status to 2." That is what this answer does.

Comment: no, you can see that alter procedure returns a select statement, the question was how to update those rows and still return select query